# How to create swept / chirp signal using an arbitrary waveform like an audio file

Tags: matlab, audio, signal-processing, octave

How can I create a swept / chirp signal using an arbitrary waveform from an audio file.  I can create a swept / chirp signal using matlab / octave with the code below (also see spectrum taken).

The code below works to create a swept audio signal that gradually decreases in frequency but I was hoping to get the audio file `num_01.wav` (link below) to gradually decrease in frequency also but I get a garbled audio file.

```
clc,clear all
swept_startfreq = 500;
swept_endfreq = 225;
fs = 8000;
swept_dursec = 15;  % duration of signal in seconds  
swept_t = (0:swept_dursec*fs)/fs;  % Time vector

if (swept_startfreq == swept_endfreq)
      swept_phase = swept_startfreq * swept_t;
else
    swept_alpha = abs(log(swept_endfreq/swept_startfreq))/swept_dursec;
    swept_b = (swept_startfreq - swept_endfreq)/(1 - exp(-swept_alpha*swept_dursec));
    swept_a = swept_startfreq - swept_b;

    swept_phase = swept_a*swept_t - (swept_b/swept_alpha)*exp(-swept_alpha*swept_t);
endif

swept_sig_out = .8* cos(2*pi*swept_phase); %equation used to create signal

wavwrite([swept_sig_out'] ,fs,32,strcat('/tmp/swept_sig_out.wav'));  % export file
```

Heres's a dropbox link to the file the original code above creates (a swept / chrip audio signal). [https://www.dropbox.com/s/wg8sxmsdd7hdojz/swept_sig_out.wav?dl=0#](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wg8sxmsdd7hdojz/swept_sig_out.wav?dl=0)

The frequency spectrum of the original code / chirp or swept signal it creates
[image: Frequency Spectrum]

`When I replace/add the lines:`

```
[imported_sig, fs_rate, nbitsraw] = wavread('num_01.wav');
swept_sig_out=imported_sig(:).*swept_phase(1:length(imported_sig))(:);
```

The signal created is this (dropbox link of file) https://www.dropbox.com/s/ekrcssrgie3vfgb/swept_sig_out_created_from_audio_file.wav?dl=0#

`Note: the audio test num_01.wav file I used can be found on a dropbox account`
https://www.dropbox.com/s/p37kaszqylqnkme/num_01.wav?dl=0#

I was hoping to get the audio file `num_01.wav` to gradually decrease in frequency / pitch but I get a garbled audio file, how can I go about fixing this so the audio file gradually decreases in frequency?

PS:  I'm using Octave 4.0 which is like Matlab

Comment: I'm not totally clear on what your asking here. Are you trying to mix the swept frequency into the existing sound file or alter the pitch of the existing sound file? Your code is trying to mix. If that's the case then you should divide swept_sig_out by 2 to avoid clipping.

Comment: @jaket The code above works to create a swept audio signal that gradually decreases in frequency but  I was hoping to get the audio file `num_01.wav` to gradually decrease in frequency also but I get a garbled mess when I add the two lines as mentioned.

Comment: That's the same thing you said in original post.  What does "was hoping to get the audio file num_01.wav to gradually decrease in frequency" mean? What is the content of num_01.wav?  If it was music, would you expect the pitch of the song to gradually decrease?

Comment: @jaket if you look at the code and the frequency spectrum above it goes from (500 to 225 hz) the lines swept_startfreq = 500; swept_endfreq = 225;  I've also included the file `num_01.wav` link to a dropbox file in the original post.  I've also included dropbox links to the files that the swept / chirp signal it creates if you want to hear what it sounds like.  I can't describe it better than gradually decrease in frequency / pitch but maybe this audio file will help. 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/wg8sxmsdd7hdojz/swept_sig_out.wav?dl=0#

Comment: I understand completely fine what a swept sine is. What I'm asking is what you are expecting as a result of your operation on num_01.wav. Either you expect "one one one one one..." where you can hear swept_sig_out.wav playing in the background or your expecting "one one one one one" gradually decreasing in pitch.

Comment: @jaket exactly I'm expecting / trying to get "one one one one one" gradually decreasing in pitch.

Comment: I think you're barking up the wrong three.  Google phase vocoder